# C++ set is slower?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I had to use a data structure which keeps the elements in some sort of order such that
I can query for least element and also insert new elements efficiently.So I chose
`set ( C++ stl)` . It takes `log(n)` time for *insertion* and `log(n)` for *deleting* least element.

So i wrote the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   set<int>s1,s2;
   set<int>::iterator it;
   int tmp,i;
   for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)s1.insert(i);
   for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)
   {
      it=s1.begin();
      s2.insert(*it);
      s1.erase(s1.begin());
   }
return 0;
}
```

but this takes `1.67` secs on my machine( *i core 3*) i expected much less `O(log(1000000)*1000000)` i.e. `2*10^7` i tried *priority queue* also it gave me the same performance. So should I implement my own *heap* to make it faster or there is some other way?

Comment: (Those (irrelevant) macros give me the creeps.)

Comment: sorry for that I just pasted my whole program ,its my template

Comment: Please explain why you expected better than 1.6s. Complexity analysis can help you predict scaling with problem size, but won't predict absolute times.

Comment: Do not even think of writing programs using macros in that way - your heading for trouble. In fact do not use macros at all in C++

Comment: @David the O(log(n)*n)~ 2*10^7 my machine does 10^9 operations per second, so i gues atleast it should have been less than a second

Comment: First obvious question: Did you compile with optimization enabled?

Comment: @migdal Nope, that logic is flawed. Read again about complexity analysis.

Comment: The cost you're paying is for allocation/freeing. Try the same test with a vector and sorting it when you actually need it in order. Use reserve() before you start inserting for max win.

Comment: @migdal The "result" of O(log(n)*n) isn't seconds, or time,

Comment: @thilo actually its a question on spoj(http://www.spoj.com/problems/HELPR2D2/) which uses this , and they run it on PENTIUM 7 for testing so it really doesn't matter how fast it is on my with optimisation enabled, it should have been a bit faster on my computer i guess.

Comment: Note that O(stuff) is not "it takes stuff instructions". It tells you how the algorithm scales, so if you benchmark with X elements, how will it scale to 2X, 4X, 10X, or something like that. The actual instructions involved in storing 1000 characters strings (e.g. parts of DNA sequences or some such) in a binary tree may well be many thousands per item, but it will still grow by log2(n) when you increase the number of items stored.

Comment: @imulsion - One good reason for not using macros is that it is easier to debug using the debugger.

Comment: Good, don't use macros unless they actually make sense to you!

Comment: @migdal, You should get used to typing these things out or making appropriate functions for them, but if you're going to reduce typing, at least make it something that gets translated into real code into your source file. I might be extremely lazy, but I just started testing being able to type `#in io` etc and have it expand to `#include <iostream>` wherever I type it. I type less and whoever reads the code sees real code. Win-win.

Comment: Are you really going to have a priority queue with 1000000 elements? Is your benchmark realistic? Is the real app going to have the bottleneck at the queue handling?

Comment: @chris I will keep that in my mind thanks.@DavidYes the queue can have 10^6 elements.

Answer (score 10):

What you are doing is one of the hardest thing a balanced binary search tree could suffer. You keep insert items to the right most side of the tree and keep deleting items from left most side, making the tree always has to re-balance itself.

Answer (score 4):

There's a template called `priority_queue` that handles the workload you described much better.  It's a max-heap, not a min-heap, but it allows you to pass a custom comparator as a template argument.  It's implemented by maintaining heap ordering on an underlying container that's usually a `vector`.

`set` is implemented as a balanced binary tree.  That means every insertion and query does about log2(n) highly nonlocal memory accesses; think of it as log2(n) cache misses.  Heaps do much better.  These are particularly rough on modern processors and it's not uncommon to see a large constant-factor speedup when you tame your memory access patterns.

Comment: For large data-set priority_queue maybe a little more cache efficient than set or map, but not much. Actually they suffer the same problem.

Comment: I tried prority queue only gives a minimal speed up then i implemented my own heap and it take 0.27 sec , I guess it is indeed due to freeing and allocation of memory in case of set.

Answer (score 0):

```
class heap
{
   int heap[1000001],siz;
   public:
   int ini()
   {
      siz=0;
   }
   int size()
   {
      return siz;
   }
   int top()
   {
     return heap[1];
   }
  void insert(int num)
  {
     siz++;
     heap[siz]=num;
     int pos=siz,tmp;
     while(pos>1)
     {
    if(heap[pos]<heap[pos/2])
    {
       tmp=heap[pos];
       heap[pos]=heap[pos/2];
       heap[pos/2]=tmp;
    }
    else break;
     }
  }
  void del()
  {
     if(siz==1)
     {
    siz=0;
    return;
     }
     heap[1]=heap[siz];
     siz--;
     int pos=1,tmp;
     while(2*pos<=siz)
     {
    if(2*pos+1<=siz)
    {
       if(heap[2*pos]<=heap[2*pos+1])
       {
          if(heap[pos]>heap[2*pos])
          {
         tmp=heap[pos];
         heap[pos]=heap[2*pos];
         heap[2*pos]=tmp;
         pos=2*pos;
          }
          else break;
       }
       else if(heap[2*pos+1]<=heap[2*pos])
       {
          if(heap[pos]>heap[2*pos+1])
          {
         tmp=heap[pos];
         heap[pos]=heap[2*pos+1];
         heap[2*pos+1]=tmp;
         pos=2*pos+1;
          }
          else break;
       }
    }
    else 
    {

       if(heap[pos]>heap[2*pos])
       {
          tmp=heap[pos];
          heap[pos]=heap[2*pos];
          heap[2*pos]=tmp;
          pos=2*pos;
       }

       else break;

    }
     }
  }

};
int main()
{
   int i,tmp;
   heap a1,a2;
   a1.ini();a2.ini();
   for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)a1.insert(i);
   for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)
   {
      tmp=a1.top();
      a2.insert(tmp);
      a1.del();
   }
}
```

I implemented my own heap and did the same thing it runs in now 0.25 seconds.I guess it is indeed allocation and freeing of memory that makes set slower.